# bulk file copying/sorting

Tags: file, sorting

I am looking at moving a huge number (1 million+) of image (.tif) files from location A to location B on a virtual server.

The difference between location A and B are the folder structures, and currently the source and destination paths for each file is stored in a SAS table. So what we would do is run a SAS script to look up the source and destination for each file and perform a copy command - this takes quite a bit of time (16+ hours for 1 million+ files).

What I would like to know is if there are more efficient ways to move and sort large number of files that each have unique sources and destinations? The criteria for source and destination is based off of values found in the SAS table so there's no avoiding the need to read from the table.

Structure example:

Source: server\year_&_month\barcode_ID\image_ID.tif

Destination: server\month\port\traveler_type\day_of_entry\barcode_ID\image_ID.tif

As you can see, some of the parameters are the same (server, month, barcode ID, image ID), but the destination has more levels.

Comment: Not sure there is anyway to speed the copying of the files.  Most likely that is limited by the disk drives and the connections.  If you are trying to write a million files to the same disk you will have a lot of contention.  If you can make it so that the targets are scattered across many physical drives then you will get better throughput.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yeah, Just wasn't sure there's any good option to do this with each file each having unique source and destination (that has to be retrieved from a SAS table).